# how can I get more details about security alert received vie Microsoft Security Graph API?

Tags: security, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Security Graph API to get alerts into SIEM. And some of the alerts I get have very little amount of details. Here is the example, with some information edited, but all fields are present:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#security/alerts/$entity",
    "id": "df59a25b7179858f9d891672dee4e4a48b718fe9271e6867b20a998463b1a703",
    "azureTenantId": "a2c874c8-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-fXXX56f81134",
    "azureSubscriptionId": null,
    "riskScore": null,
    "tags": [],
    "activityGroupName": null,
    "assignedTo": null,
    "category": "AnomalousToken",
    "closedDateTime": null,
    "comments": [],
    "confidence": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2022-01-05T20:52:18Z",
    "description": "Anomalous token indicates that there are abnormal characteristics in the token such as token duration and authentication from unfamiliar IP address",
    "detectionIds": [],
    "eventDateTime": "2022-01-04T12:26:36.1726686Z",
    "feedback": null,
    "incidentIds": [],
    "lastEventDateTime": null,
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-05T22:47:28.909877Z",
    "recommendedActions": [],
    "severity": "medium",
    "sourceMaterials": [],
    "status": "newAlert",
    "title": "Anomalous Token",
    "vendorInformation": {
        "provider": "IPC",
        "providerVersion": null,
        "subProvider": null,
        "vendor": "Microsoft"
    },
    "alertDetections": [],
    "cloudAppStates": [],
    "fileStates": [],
    "hostStates": [],
    "historyStates": [],
    "investigationSecurityStates": [],
    "malwareStates": [],
    "messageSecurityStates": [],
    "networkConnections": [],
    "processes": [],
    "registryKeyStates": [],
    "securityResources": [],
    "triggers": [],
    "userStates": [
        {
            "aadUserId": "7b9b7027-XXXX-XXXX-bXXX-1XXXXXXX9e7",
            "accountName": "NicXXX.XXXXX",
            "domainName": "XXX.co.uk",
            "emailRole": "unknown",
            "isVpn": null,
            "logonDateTime": "2022-01-04T12:26:36.1726686Z",
            "logonId": null,
            "logonIp": "102.11.1.15",
            "logonLocation": "Accra, Greater Accra, GH",
            "logonType": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "riskScore": null,
            "userAccountType": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "NicXXX.XXXXX@XXX.co.uk"
        }
    ],
    "uriClickSecurityStates": [],
    "vulnerabilityStates": []
}
```

In short, the only information I can see is that the user generated some "anomalous token" from some specific IP. But I'd like to see the hostname used, what were the token details, why it was anomalous, etc.
I can see similar alerts almost empty about failed authentication attempts (azure AD), suspicious mail forwarding rule creation (Exchange), etc - all without significant details. How can I get them? Or perhaps - how should I reconfigure the Graph or data sources, to allow Graph to get access to the details?

Comment: Please check this Document it may help you : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/dsm?topic=options-microsoft-graph-security-api-protocol-configuration

Comment: Check this as well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/concept-identity-protection-risks

Comment: Hello @washuu, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and I am also not getting the detailed information about token and hostname. Hope you are also getting **partial content: 206 error**.

If successful, this method returns a `200 OK` response code and an **alert** object in the response body. A 206-error code indicates that one or more of the bulk actions failed when it was federated out to its provider. The response will contain success/error data from the individual providers for each threat intelligence indicator. For more information you can follow this [Microsoft Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/alert-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

[image]

I read several Microsoft documents and found that Anomalous Token comes under [sign in risk detection.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/concept-identity-protection-risks) A sign-in risk represents the probability that a given authentication request isn't authorized by the identity owner.

These risks can be calculated in real-time or calculated offline using **Microsoft's internal and external threat intelligence sources including security researchers**, **law enforcement professionals, security teams at Microsoft**, and other trusted sources.

> Anomalous Token Detection Type is offline.This detection indicates
> that there are abnormal characteristics in the token such as an
> unusual token lifetime or a token that is played from an unfamiliar
> location. This detection covers Session Tokens and Refresh Tokens.

ANOMALOUS TOKEN DETECTION [plan](https://dirteam.com/sander/2021/08/03/whats-new-in-azure-active-directory-for-july-2021/) is communicated by Microsoft in July 2021

> Anomalous token detection is now available in Azure AD Identity
> Protection. This feature can detect that there are abnormal
> characteristics in the token such as **time active and authentication
> from unfamiliar IP address.**

So from the above conclusion would suggest you to raise a [Microsoft support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), I think They can help to route to security team in Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, the token had some abnormal characteristics, but in the quoted alert, there are no details, like source IP or the lifetime of the ticket!          
Unfortunately, I don't have any paid Support  Plan available - it looks that submitting any technical ticket (even during the working hours) requires to have a paid Support Plan. Here is the link if anyone wants to take a look at the options: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/